# AWS CloudSearch Search on literal arrays

Tags: arrays, search, literals, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm using AWS CloudSearch on a project. I can make everything i need with it except searching terms on a literal array. Example:

Imagine a domain for  book info. Imagine a literal array index called `book_types`. I want to get all books that have a specific type on the `book_types` index (i'm using HTTP requests). I've tried the following without success:

```
xxx.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q.parser=structured&q=(and(term+field%3Dbook_types+%27Thriller%27))&size=1

xxx.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q.parser=structured&q=(and(prefix+field%3Dbook_types+%27Thriller%27))&size=1

xxx.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q.parser=structured&q=(and(phrase+field%3Dbook_types+%27Thriller%27))&size=1
```

I've success in search on a literal index but can't get any results every time i search a literal array index.

How can we build a HTTP request to get results from a literal array index?